# Why when I do a console.log is my object within a function returned as 'undefined'? (Learning about creation phase, execution phase)

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, executioncontext

I am trying to understand execution contexts, creation phase, and execution phase.

I was wondering, could someone please help me to understand why,

```
console.log(thisFunction.ojbect1);
```

Returns - 'undefined'.

I would have thought that, after the creation phase, when the variables are assigned 'undefined', the execution phase is run, where the variable, is then filled with the object.

So why do I get the 'undefined' for 'object1', and not the whole object?

Many thanks. Code below.

```
var thisFunction = function(){
    var object1 = {
        firstname: 'Mark',
        printName: function(){
        console.log(this.firstname);
        }
    };

    object1.printName();
};

thisFunction();
console.log(thisFunction.object1);
```

Comment: `object1` is a local variable for `thisFunction` so can't be accessed implicitly outside the scope of `thisFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

"Object1" is not a property of "thisFunction", that is why you can not call it. "Object1" is a variable created inside the scope of "thisFunction".

You can only reach variables of parent scopes.

Here are some interesting reads if you want to know more about function scopes.

- [Ryanmorr - Understanding scope and context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)
- [MDN - Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question though was more, why was Object1 assigned the variable 'Undefined'. i.e Why was it assigned 'undefined', in the creation phase, and then never assigned the object in the execution phase?

I'm probably not making any sense here :)

Comment: Every time `thisFunction` is called a new scope is created. This scope has the local variable `object1`. Therefor it is undefined outside of `thisFunction`.

When you type `thisFunction.object1` you do not call `thisFunction`. Instead you are treating `thisFunction` as an object and looking for a property named `object1`. This do not work since `thisFunction` is a function.

Comment: You mention: 'thisFunction is a function', and I think this is where I am getting confused. Aren't functions not also objects in javascript?

Comment: Functions are not objects, but they can be made into an object by using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanks very much Lars-Kristian. Then I am being confused by the person whom I am learning from, as they said that - 'Functions are objects'. I read this line from the Mozilla functions page. ' In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. ' My head is spinning :D

Comment: Ah, I think I see where my difficulty is coming from. The difference between, a property, and a variable in JavaScript. The former belonging to an object, and the later relating to an execution context. Am I making sense :) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use **this** to assign a variable to function-object **thisFunction**.
2. Then you need to use **new** to create an object of **thisFunction**.

This works as you except:

```
    var thisFunction = function(){

    this.object1 = {
        firstname: 'Mark',
        printName: function(){
        console.log(this.firstname);
        }
    };

    this.object1.printName();
};

var tf = new thisFunction();
console.log(tf.object1);
```

Using `typeof` helps you better understand the difference between object and function:

```
console.log(typeof thisFunction);
console.log(typeof tf);
console.log(typeof tf.object1);
console.log(typeof tf.object1.firstname);
```

Output:

> function
>   object
>   object
>   string

See this example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LF2LkxShNQAm8uVam4yG?p=info)

Comment: Thanks, for that, still have some learning to do, to fully understand what's happening under the hood with your solution.